# customizing np.fft.fft function in python

Tags: python, numpy, integration, fft

I wish to perform a fourier transform of  the function 'stress' from 0 to infinity and extract the real and imaginary parts. I have the following code that does it using a numerical integration technique:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import trapz
import fileinput
import sys,string 

window = 200000 # length of the array I wish to transform (number of data points)
time = np.linspace(1,window,window)
freq = np.logspace(-5,2,window)
output = [0]*len(freq)
for index,f in enumerate(freq):
    visco = trapz(stress*np.exp(-1j*f*t),t)
    soln = visco*(1j*f)
    output[index] = soln

print 'f storage loss'
for i in range(len(freq)):
    print freq[i],output[i].real,output[i].imag
```

This gives me a nice transformation of my input data.

Now I have an array of size 2x10^6, and using the above technique is not feasible(computation time scales as O(N^2)), so I have turned to the inbuilt fft function in numpy. 
There aren't too many arguments that you can specify to change this function, and so I'm finding it difficult to customize it to my needs.
So far I have

```
import numpy as np
import fileinput
import sys, string

np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')

N = len(stress)
fvi = np.fft.fft(stress,n=N)
gprime = fvi.real
gdoubleprime = fvi.imag
for i in range(len(stress)):
    print gprime[i], gdoubleprime[i]
```

And it's not giving me accurate results.

The DFT in python is of the form A_k = summation(a_m * exp(-2*pi*i*m*k/n)) where the summation is from m = 0 to m = n-1 (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/routines.fft.html). How can I change it to the form that I have mentioned in my first code, i.e. exp(-1j*freq*t) (freq is the frequency and t is the time which have already been predefined)? Or is there a post processing of the data that I have to do?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: I could set stress=1, but what is `t` (is it  `time`?) ,   what is `w`?

Comment: The general answer is that a FFT will compute all spectral features that you can legitimately obtain from the Fourierintegral. Using the Fourierintegral you could easily compute frequencies, that are not giving new information (convolution of Fouriersignal with window). In the FFT the time range will give your frequency resolution (df=1/T), the time resolution determines your highest frequency (fmax= 0.5*1/dt) .